# A simple Google Sheets Boomi Operation does not upload data to Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, connector, boomi

[Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eABic.png)

Hi,

I am creating a simple Boomi process that takes a flat file, maps it to the JSON Request for a Google Sheet & uploads the flat file data to an online Google Sheet.

Although the process runs & completes, it does not upload the information to my Google Sheet.

The process begins with a Start - No Data.

It then goes to a message shape. Where the name, sheetTitle & Spreadsheet ID are set.

It then goes to a Data Process Shape where the formatting for the flat file is split for entries to the Spreadsheet.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG6Mn.png)
Here the Flat File is mapped to the elements of the JSON formatted Google Sheets Request. The Request was generated by the Google Sheets Import Wizard.

[Connector Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5m4z.png)

[Google Sheets Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cSFg.png)

These are the Parameters of the Google Sheets Connector. The connection is good.

[Google Sheets Operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgvvH.png)

The operation is RecordData object type & the Request + Response Profiles were created by import, **Google Sheets Import Wizard** where Atom, Connection, Spreadsheet ID, Sheet Title were set.

After the Process is ran I am expecting for the Spreadsheet to contain data but it is still empty.

How can I get some simple data into my Google Sheets? Any help would be much appreciated.

[Shape Source Data from Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gTk8.png)

[Shape Source Data from Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dkKf.png)